# Node FS.existsSync returning false on a file that exists

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron, fs

I'm currently trying to find out if a file exists before I run fs.appendFile() so that I can determine if I need to insert some text at the beginning of the document, or if I need to insert a line break.

I've written a function that when I debug it outside of the electron (this is for an electron app) process fs.existsSync returns true or false as expected. However, when I run this in the app, it only returns false, regardless of if it actually does exist or not.

```
function foo(){
    const USER = process.env['USERPROFILE'].split(path.sep)[2];
    const fpath = `C:/Users/${USER}/OneDrive/dir/filename.txt`;
    let text = "text";
    const exists = fs.existsSync(fpath);
    console.log(exists); // false no matter what
    if(!exists){
        text = "foo";
    }else{
        text = "bar";
    }
    fs.appendFile(fpath, myob_import_text, (err) => { // Only ever adds "foo" to the document.
        if(err) throw err;
    });  
}
```

I assume this has something to do with running inside the context of electron vs running in just a node environment, but I can't figure out how to work around this, so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you do a console.log(fpath) to see if the path points to the existing file?

Comment: @JelmerJellema when I console.log(fpath) it returns:
    C:/Users/Office/OneDrive/dir/filename.txt

That's the correct file path to the file. I thought possibly that existsSync doesn't like being passed a string, but then I wouldn't have a clue how to pass it the right data.

Comment: so this means your problem is in the line creating setting const USER.  Or is 'office' the user?

Comment: why not skip const USER and just set fpath to `\`${process.env['USERPROFILE']}/OneDrive/dir/filename.txt\``?

Comment: So, this alone didn't actually work, but it did lead me to discover that I had my slashes the wrong way around. So my string should have been:
    `${process.env['USERPROFILE']}\\OneDrive\\dir\\filename.txt`

Thanks for your help @JelmerJellema

Comment: Note that checking if a file exists before writing to it is a race condition and a well-known antipattern.